# ARSession crashes with Testflight, not with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I have made an app that tracks 2D body motion data using the back camera. I have followed [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) to create an ARView from the storyboard, and have added this code in my viewDidAppear:

```
arView.session.delegate = self

// If the iOS device doesn't support body tracking, raise a developer error for
// this unhandled case.
guard ARBodyTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else {
    fatalError("This feature is only supported on devices with an A12 chip")
}

// Run a body tracking configration.
let configuration = ARBodyTrackingConfiguration()
arView.session.run(configuration)
```

When I open the app everything works perfectly when installing from Xcode, but the app crashes when installing from TestFligth. Crash log shows me the last backtrace log at `arView.session.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround in case someone faces the same problem. According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes) this is a known issue in XCode 11. To solve it, you need to manually add RealityKit to your target’s Link Binary with Libraries build phase. Hope this helps